Is there racial discrimination at Tbilisi airport?
I’m planning a vacation to Georgia and surrounding countries later this year...very excited. Can't wait to experience the culture and history of this unique region.
I have found numerous posts on discussions forums (e.g., TripAdvisor, Reddit etc.) where some travelers of South Asian or Arab heritage commented on discriminatory behavior at Tbilisi airport. They claim this particular group has often been denied entry without explanation. I know these stories might not be true, and that sometimes only negative stories get highlighted while hundreds of positive stories get unmentioned.
I am a US citizen of South Asian heritage and I am wondering if this is something to worry about when I travel to Tbilisi. The US State Department’s travel site tells me that no visa is required for US citizens. Is there a chance I'll be denied entry based on my appearance?

I doubt you'll have the slightest issue with immigration folks provided the purpose of your visit is a legitimate vacation and you're not working for the kind of folks that might raise questions as to intent.

It's not too uncommon for ex-Soviet border officials to exercise racial profiling, so if you get a piece of work for an officer they could suspect your US passport to be fake (they often fail to realise how ethnically diverse the US is). I know a Belgian bloke with Congolese parents who was detained for an hour at Kutaisi airport while his ID card was checked in-depth - the first-line officer openly accused him of lying about being Belgian. Usually, though, they'll process Western nationals rather swiftly; you just look into the camera to get photographed and then get stamped in.

Thanks Crazydre. My experience is congruent with your comment. I have traveled to 70+ countries and never had a major problem. Every now and then there's an atypical immigration officer but that could happen to anyone.
